# Why is my Rust version of "wc" slower than the one from GNU coreutils?

Tags: rust, benchmarking, gnu-coreutils

Consider this program:

```
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut n = 0;
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for _ in stdin.lock().lines() {
        n += 1;
    }
    println!("{}", n);
}
```

Why is it over 10x as slow as the GNU version of wc? Take a look at how I measure it:

```
$ yes | dd count=1000000 | wc -l
256000000
1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
512000000 bytes (512 MB, 488 MiB) copied, 1.16586 s, 439 MB/s
$ yes | dd count=1000000 | ./target/release/wc
1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
512000000 bytes (512 MB, 488 MiB) copied, 41.685 s, 12.3 MB/s
256000000
```

Comment: Just a guess, but: I'd say `wc` *probably* isn't heap-allocating a new dynamically resized string for every single line.

Comment: There are minimal coreutils written in Rust for Redox; you can check [their implementation of wc](https://github.com/redox-os/coreutils/blob/master/src/bin/wc.rs).

Comment: Isn't it a bit off to describe this as "Rust's version of wc", rather than *your* version of `wc`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you could probably argue both ways - either that I didn't optimize it well (and judging by the answers I got here, it's not simple) or that Rust didn't.

Answer (score 20):

There are many reasons why your code is way slower than the original `wc`. There are a few things you pay for which you actually don't need at all. By removing those, you can already get a quite substantial speed boost.

#### Heap allocations

[`BufRead::lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) returns [an iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Lines.html) which yields `String` elements. Due to this design, it will (it has to!) allocate memory for every single line. The `lines()` method is a convenient method to write code easily, but it isn't supposed to be used in high performance situations.

To avoid allocating heap memory for every single line, you can use [`BufRead::read_line()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) instead. The code is a bit more verbose, but as you can see, we are reusing the heap memory of `s`:

```
let mut n = 0;
let mut s = String::new();
let stdin = io::stdin();
let mut lock = stdin.lock();
loop {
    s.clear();
    let res = lock.read_line(&mut s);
    if res.is_err() || res.unwrap() == 0 {
        break;
    }
    n += 1;
}
println!("{}", n);
```

On my notebook, this results in:

```
$ yes | dd count=1000000 | wc -l
256000000
1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
512000000 bytes (512 MB, 488 MiB) copied, 0,981827 s, 521 MB/s

$ yes | dd count=1000000 | ./wc 
1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
512000000 bytes (512 MB, 488 MiB) copied, 6,87622 s, 74,5 MB/s
256000000
```

As you can see, it improved things *a lot*, but is still not equivalent.

#### UTF-8 validation

Since we are reading into a `String`, we are validating the raw input from stdin to be proper UTF-8. This costs time! But we are only interested in the raw bytes, since we only need to count the newline characters (`0xA`). We can get rid of UTF-8 checks by using a `Vec<u8>` and [`BufRead::read_until()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_until):

```
let mut n = 0;
let mut v = Vec::new();
let stdin = io::stdin();
let mut lock = stdin.lock();
loop {
    v.clear();
    let res = lock.read_until(0xA, &mut v);
    if res.is_err() || res.unwrap() == 0 {
        break;
    }
    n += 1;
}
println!("{}", n);
```

This results in:

```
1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
512000000 bytes (512 MB, 488 MiB) copied, 4,24162 s, 121 MB/s
256000000
```

That's a 60% improvement. But the original `wc` is still faster by a factor of 3.5x!

#### Further possible improvements

Now we used up all the low hanging fruit to boost performance. In order to match `wc`s speed, one would have to do some serious profiling, I think. In our current solution, `perf` reports the following:

- around 11% of the time is spent in `memchr`; I don't think this can be improved
- around 18% is spent in `<StdinLock as std::io::BufRead>::fill_buf()` and
- around 6% is spent in `<StdinLock as std::io::BufRead>::consume()`

A huge part of the remaining time is spent in `main` directly (due to inlining). From the looks of it, we are also paying a bit for the cross platform abstraction. There is some time spent for `Mutex` methods and stuff.

But at this point, I'm just guessing, because I don't have the time to look into this further. Sorry :<

But please note, that `wc` is an old tool and is highly optimized for the platform it's running on and for the task it's performing. I guess that knowledge about Linux internal things would help performance a lot. This is really specialized, so I wouldn't expect to match the performance that easily.

Comment: That's `14.9 MB/s` for me.

Comment: @d33tah: I know, it's still not nearly equivalent. Right now, I'm looking deeper into this. Reasons might include UTF8 validation and stuff like that. Will update the answer when I'm sure about the results. If I don't find out anything useful, I'll delete it. Sorry for posting an incomplete answer :'(

Comment: I'd just title it "minor improvement" at the beginning of the post and keep it as it is ;)

Comment: This might be a hint - on IRC I got this 17.5MB version: `println!("{}", stdin.lock().bytes().filter_map(|b| b.ok()).filter(|b| *b == b'\n').count());`

Comment: @d33tah I updated my answer. The IRC solution runs slower than the solution in my answer... at least on my notebook.

Comment: Interesting. The code from "UTF-8 validation" section is still only 19.1MB/s for me.

Comment: To really get this fast you probably to read chunks of 16/32 byte and then use sse/avx + bmi2 to count the numbers of OxAs. I don't know if that's possible with rust but that should speed things up A LOT: No branchmisse and around 32 byte per cycle if you could read from L1.

Comment: I would expect to be able to do perform `wc` without copying bytes in the user-land. A single pass that counts various marker bytes (SSE/AVX) should be sufficient, and would make this an I/O or memory-bound program. Anything on top (using `String`/`Vec`, ...) is going to add some overhead.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: and Lukas: GNU `wc` is *not* "highly optimized" on x86-64  Linux.  It uses a byte-at-a-time loop that doesn't get auto-vectorized (at least on Arch Linux, maybe they use `-O2`?).  I ran `wc -l` inside GDB and hit control-C to stop it in a hot loop.  With `stepi`, I can see it doing  `xor ecx,ecx` / `cmp    BYTE PTR [rax-0x1],0xa` / `sete   cl` / `add    rdx,rcx` inside a non-unrolled loop.  So it doesn't even run at 1 byte per cycle.  Even some loop unrolling would help.  Manual vectorization with SSE `pcmpeqb` / `psubb` could give it a factor if 16 speedup if we aren't I/O bound.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: so it's not optimized in any target-specific ways, but it does use an adaptive strategy for short line vs. long lines, using `memchr` to find the next `'\n` for long lines, vs. `while (p != end) lines += *p++ == '\n';` for short lines. 
 https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/wc.c#L313.  gcc or clang could auto-vectorize that, because the loop trip count is known before it's entered.  That happens with `-O3`, but it uses punpckl/h up to qwords inside the inner loop, rather than accumulating byte sums for a while or using `psadbw`.  only ~2x faster `-l`, slow `-w`

Answer (score 12):

This is because your version is in no way equivalent to the GNU one which doesn't allocate any memory for strings, but only moves the file pointer and increments different counters. In addition, it processes raw bytes while Rust's `String` must be valid UTF-8.

[GNU wc source](https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/manual/html_node/Source-of-wc-command.html)

Answer (score 10):

Here's a version I got from Arnavion on #rust-beginners IRC:

```
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let mut buffer = [0u8; 1024];
    let stdin = ::std::io::stdin();
    let mut stdin = stdin.lock();
    let mut wc = 0usize;
    loop {
        match stdin.read(&mut buffer) {
            Ok(0) => {
                break;
            },
            Ok(len) => {
                wc += buffer[0..len].into_iter().filter(|&&b| b == b'\n').count();
            },
            Err(err) => {
                panic!("{}", err);
            },
        }
    };
    println!("{}", wc);
}
```

This gets performance very close to what original `wc` does.